# Can one cancel a multipartFormData upload Alamofire request?

Tags: multipartform-data, alamofire

I have a `multipartFormData` upload request that I want to store in a property so that I can allow the user to cancel it at any moment.

It looks like this :

```
var uploadRequest : Alamofire.Request?
self.uploadRequest = Alamofire.upload(.POST, apiURL, multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
```

I'm receiving the following `error` though :

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

For the `Alamofire` HTTP method param.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `Method.POST` or `Alamofire.Method.POST` instead of just `.POST`